# What is the difference between "Don't Starve" (PC) and "Don't Starve: Pocket Edition"?

Tags: dont-starve, version-differences

*Don't Starve: Pocket Edition* is [available for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dont-starve-pocket-edition/id1012298403?mt=8). I own it, but I do not own the PC version.

*Don't Starve* is currently on sale in the Steam Summer sale, and I am considering buying it. However, if it is exactly the same as the PE version, I might reconsider.

**Is *Don't Starve* for the PC any different to *Don't Starve: Pocket Edition?*** If so, how is it different?

Answer (score 5):

> Don't Starve: Pocket Edition is a full port of the PC version, which means the only real difference between the two is the interface.

(Source: http://www.148apps.com/reviews/dont-starve-pocket-edition-review/)

Comment: Does it include Reign of the Giants or Shipwrecked?

Comment: @angussidney Probably yes. Watch some gameplays.